# How to read a csv file in R appropriately

Tags: r, read.csv

I have problem reading the .csv file as below in R appropriately. Anyone knows the efficient way? You may download the csv file from the link (in the link https://gtexportal.org/home/gene/). You need to click on the csv to download it.

using the:

data<-read.csv('GTExPortal.csv',sep=","), read the data in one column.

Comment: read.csv(), read the data in one column

Comment: Try: `library(readr)
GTExPortal <- read_delim("GTExPortal.csv", delim = ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem,  This works for me: `read.csv("gtex portal.csv")`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the the information in the comment.  Either provide a direct URL to the file or else provide instructions on how to download it once you are on the linked to page.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck please see the update in my question. I have provided the URL and where you can download it. thanks

Comment: @ 
Dave2e
what is the dim() of the data that you read, for me it shows in one column.

Comment: What does `readLines("GTEPortal.csv", n=5)` return? In your picture the first column name is not quoted nor are the values in the first column. If those are row names, that could be the problem. I have not been able to download the .csv file. Clicking the link and the "CSV" tab, I get only the column headings.

Comment: As with @Dave2e when I go to the linked-to page, press csv near the top it does download a file.  That file has only one row of data but that row is correctly read into a data frame with 5 separate fields using `read.csv("GTEx Portal.csv")`.    I am using "R version 4.2.1 Patched (2022-10-07 r83044 ucrt)" on Windows.

Comment: readLines("GTEPortal.csv", n=5) this could not help

Comment: So far none of the solutions work. No one could help.

Comment: Multiple people have not been able to reproduce the problem based on the description in the question so it is not that the solutions don't work but the question has not communicated the problem.

Comment: @
G. Grothendieck
The .csv file can be downloaded from the URL link I have provided in the question. When I use data = read.csv(") it gives me a data frame with nrow =19848  and ncol= 1. which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
library(haven)
data<-read.csv('your path',sep=",")
```

or

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
data<-read_csv('your path')
```